# Certbot - DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for xxx - check that a DNS records exists for this

Tags: subdomain, certbot, godaddy-api

So I tried to run the following

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx --dry-run -d subdomain.domain.com -d www.subdomain.domain.com
```

That gave me a DNS problem, however, it worked when running

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx --dry-run -d subdomain.domain.com
```

Am I missing something in my DNS records?

I have sucessfully run

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx --dry-run -d domain.com -d www.domain.com
```

Do I need to make a specific DNS record for the ´´www´´ part if I use subdomains?

**Edit**
Result of running ´´dig subdomain.domain.com´´

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1ubuntu2.1-Ubuntu <<>> subdomain.domain.co.uk
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45932
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;subdomain.domain.co.uk.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
subdomain.domain.co.uk.    1800    IN      A       xxx.yyy.aa.dd

;; Query time: 88 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 07 11:24:26 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64
```

Comment: "Do I need to make a specific DNS record for the ´´www´´ part if I use subdomains?" 
Yes! You'll need a `CNAME` record for the `www` domain. Please show results of a `dig subdomain.domain.com` command!

Comment: i posted that right now

Comment: No problem! It worked? I guess you should ad a `CNAME DNS`; `www.subdomain CNAME @`

Comment: i had same issue with nginx and certbot. i added CNAME record in AWS Route53 for subdomain www and pointed it to domain. Ex: if domain is abc.com then create CNAME record with name www and value as abc.com. post that certbot generated certificate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Adding proper answer from the question:

> Create an type A entry with the host "www.subdomain" and you're good

I'd add to wait anywhere between 5 minutes to an hour for the record to take effect and for `certbot` to be able to see it, from my experience.

Comment: Where applicable, instead of an `A` DNS record, a `CNAME` DNS record can also resolve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I didn't add `www` to my domain
add **A record** pointing to server

```
www.mydomain.com
```

Al together you need only two A records in domain pointing to your server ip with and without **www**

```
mydomain.com
```

Hope this helps !!!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

> If you are using subdomain than for the subdomain you don't need www.

The modified command is as follows:
`sudo certbot certonly --nginx --dry-run -d subdomain.com -d www.subdomain.com`

Comment: did you mean to write "www.subdomain.com" in one of those?

Comment: yes instead of writing www.subdomain.com go with subdomain.com

Comment: Why would you want to add the same domain twice?

Answer (score -1):

I forget to add www A record in my godaddy DNS settings
[You May try this one hope for best...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLY0N.png)

Comment: The other answers already say to add the "www" A record. Why is another answer needed?